# How to set a column containing NULL values as secondary primary key of a DataTable

Tags: .net, winforms, datatable, .net-2.0

I have a `DataTable` that was filled with a SQL statement using JOINs. Inside the `DataTable`, `ID` and `Category` are a unique pair, `ID` itself is not unique.

`Category` is allowed to contain NULL values. I want to set them as `PrimaryKey` of the `DataTable` to be able to find rows using the `Find(...)` method.

However, when I try to set `ID` and `Category` as the `PrimaryKey` property of the `DataTable`, I get a `System.Data.DataException`.

Code:

```
dt.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {dt.Columns.Item("ID"), dt.Columns.Item("Category")}
```

Exception (translated):

> Column 'Category' has null values in it

How can I still set `ID` and `Category` as `PrimaryKey`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until you fill values for Null columns, it will not allow to set the Primary Key. Primary key concept itself is "NOT NULL" columns.

From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z24kefs8(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When you identify a single DataColumn as the PrimaryKey for a DataTable, the table automatically sets the AllowDBNull property of the column to false and the Unique property to true. **For multiple-column primary keys, only the AllowDBNull property is automatically set to false.**